# "The associated workflow has been deprecated." error

Tags: 2013, list, workflow, feature

I've got 2013 workflows, deployed from WSP package. After last Deploy from VS2013 I've got workflows behaving the way that first execution on item created is ended after starting with the "The associated workflow has been deprecated. " error, and next instance is started of the workflow which is stuck after starting. I've tried removing workflow associations from lists and then reactivating workflow feature, but that doesn't help. Any ideas?

EDIT

here's screen of the ended workflow, that's Polish UI, but you should get the idea:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I resolved it by clicking on the `workflow name in list settings -> Workflows and then clicking on OK on the association page`.

(Which probably reassociated the new version in the background.)